# Show that the statements about maps are equivalent

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field and $V,W,X$ $\mathbb{K}$-vector spaces.

Let $\phi:V\rightarrow W$, $\psi:W\rightarrow X$ be linear maps and let $\phi$ be injective and let $\psi$ be surjective.

I want to show that the following statements are equivalent:

(i) $\psi\circ \phi$ is an isomorphism of vector spaces.

(ii) It holds that $W=\text{Image}(\phi)+\ker (\psi)$ and $\text{Image}(\phi)\cap \ker (\psi)=\{0\}$.

$$$$

For the direction $(i)\rightarrow (ii)$ do we use the rank nullity theorem?

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to show that if (i) holds, then $\mathrm{im}\,\phi \cap \ker\psi = 0$. Obviously $\mathrm{im}\,\phi + \ker\psi$ is a subspace of $W$, so we only need to show that the dimensions are the same: 
$$\mathrm{rk}\,\phi + \mathrm{null}\, \psi = \dim W.$$
You mentioned the rank-nullity theorem, which is a perfect tool for this. 
(Why $\mathrm{rk}\, \phi = \mathrm{rk\, \psi}$ holds in this case?)

Comment: Is $\mathrm{im}\,\phi + \ker\psi$ a subspace of $W$ because the range of $\phi$ is $W$ and the domain of $\phi$ is $W$ ?

Comment: Could we also show the other way? I mean $W\subseteq \mathrm{im}\,\phi + \ker\psi$ and use then the dimensions? Or is the other way better?

Comment: Or... if we show both sides we don't need the dimensions, right?

Comment: So we can show that $W\subseteq \mathrm{im}\,\phi + \ker\psi$ and $\mathrm{im}\,\phi + \ker\psi \subseteq W$ and this means that $W=\mathrm{im}\,\phi + \ker\psi$ and then to show that $\mathrm{im}\,\phi \cap \ker\psi = 0$ we take an element at the intersection and show that it is zero. Is evrything correct? Could you give me also a hint for the other direction?

Comment: Sure, you can show $W\subseteq \mathrm{im}\, \phi + \ker \psi$. The dimensionality argument (with rank-nullity theorem) is probably a bit shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Since the maps $\phi,\psi$ are linear, so is $\psi\circ \phi$.

**To show (i) implies (ii) . . .**

Suppose $\psi\circ \phi$ is an isomorphism.

We want to show $W=\text{im}(\phi)+\text{ker}(\psi)$ and $\text{im}(\phi)\cap \text{ker}(\psi)=\{0\}$.

First we show $W=\text{im}(\phi)+\text{ker}(\psi)$.

The inclusion $\text{im}(\phi)+\text{ker}(\psi)\subseteq W$ is immediate.

For the reverse inclusion, let $w\in W$.

Since $\psi\circ \phi$ is an isomorphism, $\psi\circ \phi$ is surjective, hence $\psi(\phi(v))=\psi(w)$ for some $v\in V$.

Let $a=\phi(v)$ and let $b=w-a$.

Clearly $a\in\text{im}(\phi)$.

Also, we have $\psi(a)=\psi(\phi(v))=\psi(w)$, hence
$$\psi(b)=\psi(w-a)=\psi(w)-\psi(a)=0$$
so $b\in\text{ker}(\psi)$.

Thus we have $w=a+b\in \text{im}(\phi)+\text{ker}(\psi)$.

It follows that $W\subseteq \text{im}(\phi)+\text{ker}(\psi)$.

Thus we have both inclusions, so $W=\text{im}(\phi)+\text{ker}(\psi)$.

Next we show $\text{im}(\phi)\cap \text{ker}(\psi)=\{0\}$ . . .

Suppose $w\in \text{im}(\phi)\cap \text{ker}(\psi)$.

We want to show $w=0$.

Since $w\in \text{im}(\phi)$, we have $w=\phi(v)$, for some $v\in V$.

Since $w\in \text{ker}(\psi)$, we have $\psi(w)=0$, hence
$$(\psi\circ\phi)(v)=\psi(\phi(v))=\psi(w)=0$$
so $v\in \text{ker}(\psi\circ\phi)$.

Then since $\psi\circ\phi$ is an isomorphism, we get $v=0$, so $w=\phi(v)-\phi(0)=0$, as required.

It follows that $\text{im}(\phi)\cap \text{ker}(\psi)=\{0\}$.

**To show (ii) implies (i) . . .**

Assume $W=\text{im}(\phi)+\text{ker}(\psi)$ and $\text{im}(\phi)\cap \text{ker}(\psi)=\{0\}$.

To show $\psi\circ \phi$ is an isomorphism, if suffices to show that $\psi\circ \phi$ is bijective.

First we show $\psi\circ \phi$ is injective . . .

Let $v\in \text{ker}(\psi\circ \phi)$.

We want to show $v=0$.

Let $w=\phi(v)$,

Clearly $w\in\text{im}(\phi)$.

Also from $v\in \text{ker}(\psi\circ \phi)$, we get
$$\psi(w)=\psi(\phi(v))=(\psi\circ \phi)(v)=0$$
so $w\in\text{ker}(\psi)$.

Thus $w\in \text{im}(\phi)\cap \text{ker}(\psi)$, hence $w=0$.

Then $\phi(v)=w=0$, hence, since $\phi$ is injective, we get $v=0$.

It follows that $\psi\circ \phi$ is injective.

Next we show $\psi\circ \phi$ is surjective . . .

Let $x\in X$.

We want to show $x=(\psi\circ\phi)(v)$ for some $v\in V$.

Since $\psi$ is surjective, we can write $x=\psi(w)$ for some $w\in W$.

By assumption, we can write $w=a+b$, where $a\in\text{im}(\phi)$ and $b\in\text{ker}(\psi)$.

Since $a\in\text{im}(\phi)$, we can write $a=\phi(v)$ for some $v\in V$, so
$$
(\psi\circ\phi)(v)
=
\psi(\phi(v))
=
\psi(a)
=
\psi(a)+\psi(b)
=
\psi(a+b)
=
\psi(w)
=
x
$$
hence $\psi\circ\phi$ is surjective.

Thus $\psi\circ\phi$ is both injective and surjective, so $\psi\circ\phi$ is an isomorphism.

This completes the proof.

**Notes:**

- The arguments I gave did not make any assumptions about dimensionality,  and did not make any use of the Rank-Nullity Theorem.$\\[6pt]$

  I supplied a lot more detail than was strictly necessary, but I hope that doing so will flesh out the thought process. The argument can always be reduced as desired to match a preferred style.

Comment: Everything is clear, thank you so much !!! I have also an other question. Knowing that $\psi \circ\phi$ is an isomorphism, we can conclude also that $\psi$ and $\phi$ are isomorphism, right? Since $\phi$ is already injective it must also be surjective and since $\psi$ is already surjective it must also be injective, right?

Comment: We know that $n:=\dim_{\mathbb{K}}V=\dim_{\mathbb{K}}W=\dim_{\mathbb{K}}X$.

Comment: @Mary Star: If we know $\psi \circ\phi$ is an isomorphism, that implies $\phi$ is injective and $\psi$ is surjective, but $\phi$ is need not be surjective, and $\psi$ need not be injective, so $\psi$ and $\phi$ need not be isomorphisms.

Comment: @Mary Star: As regards your question about dimensions, it's not given that $V,W,X$ have equal dimensions, and it need not be the case. For example, using $V=K,W=K^2,X=K$, let $\phi$ be the map that sends $a$ to $(a,0)$, and let $\psi$ be the map that sends $(c,d)$ to $c$.

Comment: @Mary Star: Also, as I mentioned in my posted answer, my arguments did not assume anything regarding the dimensions of $V,W,X$, and in particular, those dimensions are not even required to be finite.

Comment: I am asking this, because this is the next question. So do you mean that this statement is not correct? The statement of this question is "Let $n:=\dim_{\mathbb{K}}V=\dim_{\mathbb{K}}W=\dim_{\mathbb{K}}X$. $\psi\circ\phi$ is an isomorphism $\iff$ $\phi, \psi$ are isomorphisms." Do we maybe have to use the original equivalence, that $W=\text{Image}(\phi)+\ker (\psi)$ and $\text{Image}(\phi)\cap \ker (\psi)=\{0\}$ ?

Comment: @Mary Star: That statement (the statement for the next question) is correct. If it's given that all $3$ dimensions are  equal to $n$ for some positive integer $n$, then yes, $\psi\circ\phi$ is an isomorphism if and only  $\phi, \psi$ are isomorphisms.

Comment: Could you give me a hint how we could show that?

Comment: Some preliminary general results . . .$\;$Show that for nonempty sets $A,B,C$ and functions $f,g$ with $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to C$, we have the following implications:$\;\;\;(1)\;$If $f,g$ are injective, so is $g\circ f$.$\;\;\;(2)\;$If $f,g$ are surjective, so is $g\circ f$.$\;\;\;(3)\;$If $g\circ f$ is injective, so is $f$.$\;\;\;(4)\;$If $g\circ f$ is surjective, so is $g$.

Comment: Thus if $\phi,\psi$ are isomorphism, they are bijective, hence, applying the general results, it follows that $\psi\circ\phi$ is bijective, so $\psi\circ\phi$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Now assume $n=\text{dim}(V)=\text{dim}(W)=\text{dim}(X)$, and suppose $\psi\circ\phi$ is an isomorphism. Then $\psi\circ\phi$ is bijective, hence, applying the general results, it follows that $\phi$ is injective and $\psi$ is surjective.

Comment: Since $\phi$ is injective, we have $\text{ker}(\phi)=0$, hence by the Rank-Nullity Theorem, we get $\text{dim}(\text{im}(\phi))=n$, so $\phi$ is surjective. Thus $\phi$ is bijective, hence is an isomorphism.

Comment: Since $\psi$ is surjective, we have $\text{dim}(\text{im}(\phi))=n$, hence by the Rank-Nullity Theorem, we get $\text{ker}(\phi)=0$, so $\psi$ is injective. Thus $\psi$ is bijective, hence is an isomorphism.